# Is it possible to create customizable https response in Azure Event Hub

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

**What I am looking for:**
A way to create customizable https response after send event to Event Hub.

**Why do I need it?**
To provide some information to the Event publisher which does not have permission to consume events.

Comment: Not that I am aware of. It is one way only. I suppose you could send some kind of message when you are consuming the events. Using signalr for example. But then you need to know who send it. What do you need it for?

Comment: Typical scenario: to provide communication back to Event publisher when it is behind NAT network and you don't want to use AMQP.

Comment: I do know that if you use the Azure IoT Hub, bidirectional communication is supported. It's like a wrapper around the Event Hub. Don't know whether it fits your scenario but take a look. https://blog.tallan.com/2015/12/08/azure-iot-hub-vs-event-hub/

Comment: @PeterBons Thank you for your suggestion.I will try it.